# How can we get user inputs from the keyboard in GNU Octave?

Tags: octave

Is there a command like 'scanf' in GNU Octave to read the user inputs from the keyboard?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the function is called `input`.  A simple example:

```
octave-3.2.4:3> x = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: 25
x =  25
```

See the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Terminal-Input.html#Terminal-Input) for details, like overriding the default parsing behavior.

Answer (score 3):

**In GNU Octave, How to get user input line, aka open stdin:**

Make a file called: `test.m`

Put this code in there:

```
line = fgetl(stdin);
line
```

Run it like so:

```
octave test.m
```

Enter in some words then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
5 abc 7
```

The program responds:

```
line = 5 abc 7
```

Read more about function: `fgetl` https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Line_002dOriented-Input.html#XREFfgetl

Answer (score 1):

There is `scanf` function in addition to `input` function.

For example:

```
% Get a number 
x = scanf("%d", "C");
% Get a vector of size 5
for i=1:5
    x(i) = scanf("%d", "C");
end
% Get a matrix
printf("Enter a 3x2 matrix \n ");
for i=1:3
    for j=1:2
        n(i,j) = scanf("%d", "C");
    end
end
disp(n)
```